# How can i stop Viber auto updates on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, auto-updates, viber

Is there a tricky hacky way to stop Viber auto updates on Windows?
Want to stop it.

Comment: Have you tried blocking `update.viber.com`?

Comment: Hm, it's idea, will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Open host file located in c:windows\system32\etc\driver\

copy new text line into the file content

```
127.0.0.1  update.viber.com
```

Save the file.
Restart your windows PC.
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Typical problem which pisses me off. It seems EVERY software creator believes himself to be a god and their stupid qu qu wokoo they wrote to be the king and the owner on the PC, ...not a guest, from which good behavior is expected.
It takes narcistic personality and mind of an idiot, to lag user's computers with background tasks, in times when PC rss might be needed for other things. If you that type of the personality programmer, please, please, stop writing programs. Go sell hot dogs, become painter, but whatever you do, please stay away from computers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1167328)